# Move to user defined function in asp.net code?

Tags: asp.net

I have aspx.cs code in this code when programmer enters it page load method, after checking the condition, i want to jump here:

DataTable dt = flight.InsertBooking(objBook.Id, Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["totalFare"]), objBook.ReCommission, objBook.Commission, title, fname, lname, phone, phone, email, address, "-", "-", country, pincode, objBook.BookingId, objBook.PnrNo, bookrequest.Source.ToString(), objBook.Msg, bookrequest.FareRule[0].DepartureDate, objBook.MarkUp, objBook.AdminMarkUp, bookrequest.Origin, bookrequest.Destination, bookrequest.PromotionalPlanType.ToString(), bookrequest.FareType, bookrequest.Remarks, bookrequest.SessionId, isoneway, Convert.ToString(ViewState["TrnId"]), FlType, objBook.BookingStatus, objBook.Status, passengers, Request.UserHostAddress);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your code in a function and then call it